# NSString declaration

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, nsstring

I'm using SQLite database in my application and i need to get data from table (UTF8 Cyrilic). I've tried 2 methods this

```
NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

and

```
NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

this. The first one gets data from the table but with wrong encoding. The second one doesn't give me any result and console shows

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** ?> [NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

Where I should search problem and how to work right with encodings?

Comment: Breakup the statement into two to simplify debugging. First get the sql into an `unsigned char *`, then into an `NSString *`.

Comment: Are you sure the column isn't empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
const char* str = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And sure that you store date by the same method:

```
const char* str = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Can you tell me more about second part of your message:
>And sure that you store date by the same method:
`const char* str = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: When you store string in SQLite, you must convert NSString to C-string. You can do it by this code: `const char* str = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`